# How do I remove a corrupt icon from the Windows 7 taskbar

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, icons

My company uses Office365, including Yammer. I downloaded the desktop app, but it got annoying so I uninstalled it (using the Add/Remove Programs util.)

It did uninstall the app, but did not completely remove the icon from the task bar. It's now just a blank white icon; the mouseover text does say Yammer, but right-clicking to try to unpin from the task bar doesn't show any kind of context menu.

Is there anywhere else I can get at the icon to be able to remove it? I'm OK with regedit if necessary, but don't know what key to look for.

I've tried all of the answers listed in the possible duplicate, and none of them work. There is no reference to the broken icon in the `%AppData%\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch` location, and the accepted answer of left-clicking to receive an error message does nothing.

Comment: Look in C:\Users\Your user name\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar

Comment: I've tried that; there is no reference to the broken icon in that location.